# How to add button for each row in table?

Tags: labview

Labview,

i would like to add button for each row in table and this button depends on number of rows of data in the table,Button will add programatically in each row.

Reference Image: Cross button

[image]

Comment: I don't recognize these controls. Is this a LabVIEW UI? If it is, the control must be an array of clusters. You would have to find the cluster typedef and edit that.

Comment: I added  example image from google, i need one button for each row in the table,i dont want cluster

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want. Please state it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

When do you say "Table", Are you referring to "Multi-Column ListBox" or "Table Control" or Individual 1D arrays that are arranged like a Table? There are many ways you can do this!

1. An array of Clusters as Dave_St suggested.
2. Using a Table control & Boolean Array.
3. Using a Table control & Array of Picture Ring.
4. Using individual 1D Arrays Arranged like a Table.

I'd recommend the first method. Since it makes data handling pretty easy!

But If you're going to go with any other method! You can make your boolean array background as white/transparent and place on top of a Table Column!

Example:

[image: Table Control with an Array of Picture Ring]

In the above image, I used a Table Control and an array of Picture ring. But you need to synchronize both your array's scrolling positions! Only then the user shall be able to see the correct status for the row.

It seems like you're trying to imitate a webpage form! If you want to dynamically add controls/indicators to your VI check out VI Scripting! But I'm not sure whether VI Scripting will satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other ways to get this behavior.  However, the array of clusters is probably the easiest.  Two other ways to do it are:

1. Use the glyph (symbol) functionality of a table or multicolumn listbox
2. Create a data grid or use the [DataGrid QControl](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/DataGrid_QControl).

P.S. You currently cannot programmatically add controls/indicators during run time. So [VI Scripting](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/VI_Scripting) won't help you there.